# Locale aware collation in jruby

Tags: jruby

I've tracked down a bug in the rubyrep replication library that results from Ruby's collation not being locale aware. It thinks that '-' comes before 'a' when sorting, which is not correct, at least for the en_US.UTF-8 locale (and the C locale).

Right now the database is sorting these strings in a proper locale aware way but ruby is not.

What's the easiest way for a jruby novice to get locale aware string comparisons working so I can patch this code? I'm fine with hardcoding the locale I want into the code if that's necessary.

(If there is no easy way I will abandon jruby and use [this](https://github.com/k3rni/ffi-locale) lib but I'm hoping there is a jruby way so I can keep the speed advantage)

Comment: For future reference I could have used that lib in jruby as banziman pointed out. You can also change the collation rules in postgres for a specific column and if you set the collation to 'C' then the rules match those of ruby's default <=> operator as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon my asking, but how did you figure that `-` should sort *after* `a` in UTF-8? In this ASCII-compatible block, at least, I expect `-` to come before `a`.

JRuby strives to be compatible with how MRI behaves, so no matter how MRI is behaving, this is how JRuby will behave.

Also, JRuby has FFI built in, so you are free to use the library you mention.

Comment: Not on it's own, but in a string the sort order is different (I'm not sure what collation rules are applying here, it surprised me as well). Given two strings: "l-foobar" and "lafoobar", the C locale sorts "l-foobar" first and the "en_US.UTF8" locale sorts the opposite.

Comment: Also, thank you for pointing out that JRuby has FFI built in, I did not know that and it's very helpful.